# In Linux device driver function, how to know the minor number or for which particular device this driver function has been invoked?

Tags: linux, driver, device

If there are three I2C devices as mentioned below and in the device driver init() function the following call register_chrdev(89, "i2c", &i2cfops) is invoked. Note, the name is "i2c" not "i2c-0"/"i2c-1"/"i2c-2". How in the i2cdriver_open or i2cdriver_ioctl function the drive will know the minor number or for which I2C device the function has been invoked?

Please refer below for more details.

```
crw-r--r--    1 0        0         89,   0 Jun 12 09:15 /dev/i2c-0
crw-r--r--    1 0        0         89,   1 Jun 12 09:15 /dev/i2c-1
crw-r--r--    1 0        0         89,   2 Jun 12 09:15 /dev/i2c-2
```

Application:

```
int main(void)
{
  int fd;
  fd = open("/dev/i2c-0");
  (void) ioctl(fd, ...);
  return 0;
}
```

Driver:

```
static struct file_operations i2cfops;
int i2cdriver_open(struct inode * inodePtr, struct file * filePtr);
int i2cdriver_ioctl(struct inode * inodePtr, struct file * filePtr, unsigned int ui, unsigned long ul);
int driver_init(void)
{
  i2cfops.open = &i2cdriver_open;
  i2cfops.ioctl = &i2cdriver_ioctl;
  (void) register_chrdev(89, "i2c", &i2cfops);
  return 0;
}
int i2cdriver_open(struct inode * inodePtr, struct file * filePtr)
{
  /*In here, how to know the minor number or for which I2C device this function has been invoked?*/
}
int i2cdriver_ioctl(struct inode * inodePtr, struct file * filePtr, unsigned int ui, unsigned long ul)
{
  /*In here, how to know the minor number or for which I2C device this function has been invoked?*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a general note, whenever you're posting questions about Linux kernel/driver development, always include the kernel version you're working with. It makes it much easier to give you answers that will actually work for your kernel.

This should be able to retrieve your minor number:

```c
/* Add this header if you don't already have it included */
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>

/* Add this macro function wherever you need the minor number */
unsigned int minor_num = MINOR(inodePtr -> i_rdev);
```

[This page](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.16/source/include/uapi/linux/kdev_t.h#L10) has the definition of the MINOR macro, and [this page](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.16/source/include/linux/fs.h#L603) has the definition of the inode structure for reference.

Answer (score 1):

When you create multiple device nodes using the same device driver, you have multiple devices with same major number but different minor numbers.

To retrieve which particular device of them is invoked, you just need to know the minor number of the device which was invoked in your file open() function.

```
#include <kdev_t.h>
unsigned int minor_num;
static int file_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file){
   /*The line below is to be written in your open function*/
   minor_num = MINOR(inode->i_rdev);
   printk(KERN_INFO "Device file opened\n");
   return 0;
}
```

This will give you the device number using which you can perform any device-specific tasks.

Comment: I am new to c and linux, but won't the minor_num variable be global? I.e. shared with all processes entering the driver. If it is set in every open, then it will always have the last opened file's minor number ?

Comment: minor number can usually be defined on a per-device basis. e.g. you'd have /dev/mine0 that has MAJOR==42 and MINOR==0 but /dev/mine1 that has MAJOR==42 and MINOR==1. You define that throuh `mknod /dev/mine1 c 42 1`.